# Excel :If I consider a group of rows as 1 block, and I have many blocks, how to sort at block level?

Tags: excel, sorting

See image below for example. Consider column 1 is group title for blocks of rows in column 2. And the size of the group is not equal. I have to sort Column 1 and sort the sub group in column 2. Please advice how.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, how that will sort in the fashion required. can you please elaborate? thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I dont have an english excel, so excuse wrong names please.
Ribbon "Start" -> "Sort and Filter" -> "Custom sort"
[image: Sort first column (A), then second column (B)]
Please note: All rows - of data - have to have the block identifier, to be clear: "Title 1" in your example.

Comment: *All rows have to have the block identifier* Your answer would be better by adding instructions for how to do this with a formula; and also how to subsequently hide the unwanted entries with conditional formatting.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you explain how to have a block identifier. I couldn't find anything called block identifier on google.

Comment: Hi, its not easy if its not the mother tongue. x_x "Block identifier" -> each row has to have the Letter of your "Title 1" in your example. I hope its clear now.

Comment: I am not sure if it answers my question, but thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.